# Mutate a column based on the sum of specific rows from another data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for some help here. I have two data frames, df1 and df2. I want to add an extra column to df1, based on the sum of specific rows in df2.

Df1 contains station names. Df2 contain locations, years and observations in degrees. I want a sum of degrees for each station. These degrees should be sums of specific locations for each year. 
Think of it, as “each station should get its sum of degrees, based on the given locations, for each year”. I hope to only code the station name and locations, the years in desired_output should include all years given in df2.

Failed example and desired output. I prefer to work in the tidyverse environment.

All the best

````
df1 <- data.frame(station = c("station_A", "station_B"))

df2 <- data.frame(location= c("south", "north", "north", "east", "west"), year = c(2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001), degrees = c(5,3,9,5,2))

degrees_for_each_station <-
  df1%>% 
  mutate (degrees = case_when(
    station == "station_A" ~ if_else(df2$location %in% c("north","south"),
                                            sum(df2$degrees),
                                            NA),
    station == "station_B" ~ if_else(df2$location %in% c("north","east", "west"),
                                            sum(df2$degrees),
                                            NA)))

desired_output <- data.frame(station = c("station_A", "station_A","station_B", "station_B"),
                             year = c(2000, 2001, 2000, 2001),
                             degrees = c(8,9,3,16))```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  left_join(
    df2 %>%
      mutate(
        location = case_when(
          location == 'south' ~ 'station_A',
          location %in% c('east', 'west') ~ 'station_B',
          location == 'north' ~ 'station_A, station_B'
          )
      ) %>%
      separate_rows(location, sep = ', ') %>%
      group_by(location, year) %>%
      summarise(degrees = sum(degrees)),
    by = c('station' = 'location')
  )
```

Output:

```
    station year degrees
1 station_A 2000       8
2 station_A 2001       9
3 station_B 2000       3
4 station_B 2001      16
```

Comment: It seems like I made a too simplified example. It definitely works on my example, however, I was hoping for a solution where I could tell R which locations each station should sum from. In my real dataset, each station has a large number of locations to sum from, and with this example, the problem arises when some locations are found in two or more stations.

Comment: But this example is really good and it would also work om my data, I just need to write a lot of code. Right now, I have a short list of stations, with many locations to sum from and that is going to be a line of code for each location, I was hoping for a line of code for each station (see my failed example on top).